# Merging two tables in Laravel using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, backend

How do I merge two tables using Laravel eloquent such that if a record has been merged in table A to another record in table B, it can no longer merge that record in A to another different record in B even though the merged criteria are met? Can anyone help? Here is my code:

```php
class MergedController extends Controller
{  
    public function merged(Request $request){
        $merged=DB::table('client_tutor_request1')
                    ->join('form', 'client_tutor_request1.courses', '=', 'form.specialty')
                    ->whereColumn('form.category', '=', 'client_tutor_request1.category')
                    ->whereColumn('form.state', '=', 'client_tutor_request1.state')
                    ->whereColumn('form.lga', '=', 'client_tutor_request1.lga')
                    ->select('client_tutor_request1.id', 'client_tutor_request1.customers_name', 'client_tutor_request1.customers_phone', 
                    'client_tutor_request1.courses', 'form.employees_name', 'form.state', 'form.lga', 'form.lga', 'form.city',
                     'form.address', 'form.category')
                    ->orderBy('client_tutor_request1.id')
                    ->get();
         
            // return view("employee.linkup", ["merged" => $merged]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add groupBy('client_tutor_request1.id') to prevent duplication of record

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.